# How to print wstring in gdb

Tags: gdb, wstring

How can I print wstring in gdb?

Answer (score 8):

`call printf %ls` only works sometimes, but to get it to work at all in gdb 6.3 you need the `void` cast and linefeed `\n` shown here:

```
call (void)printf("\"%ls\"\n",str.c_str())
```

here is a more reliable command you can put in your .gdbinit that also shows non-ASCII code points:

```
define wc_print
echo "
set $c = (wchar_t*)$arg0
while ( *$c )
  if ( *$c > 0x7f )
    printf "[%x]", *$c
  else
    printf "%c", *$c
  end
  set $c++
end
echo "\n
end
```

just enter `wc` (short for `wc_print`) with either a `std::wstring` or `wchar_t*`.

More detail at http://www.firstobject.com/wchar_t-gdb.htm

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you've got a `std::wstring str`. The following should work in gdb:

```
call printf("%ls", str._M_data())
```

(The -l option in printf makes it a long string, and I believe you need the "`call`" statement because the ordinary gdb printf doesn't like that option.)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, and this is gdb [PR716](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/gnatsweb.pl?cmd=view&database=gdb&pr=716), [PR1998](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/gnatsweb.pl?cmd=view&database=gdb&pr=1998), [PR2264](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/gnatsweb.pl?cmd=view&database=gdb&pr=2264). Apparently this is an often-requested feature that is not yet implemented.